# Vue.js component for picking hours

Tags: vue.js

I'm creating an application where users can order Services on specific hours. Once a Service is picked for, say 2:00pm, Feb21, no other user can order a Service for this hour (but can for 1pm and 3pm).

I've googled for "vue date picker", "vue hour table", here's a very long list of Solutions: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue/blob/master/README.md but all of them are to select dates, and there's no way to indicate that a specific hour is unavailable. Is there's any such component?

I imagine it as a table, where columns are days, and rows are continuous hours makred either available or unavailable [image]

Comment: Whatever solution you decide to go with, why don't you have a 0-24 hours in an array and append that to your date widget, if it gets selected, drop it from the array, but from a UX point, add a marker to the individual items and listen for the marker to make it un-selectable.

Comment: @FirstIndex it's about displaying it. I don't want to do it by hand

Comment: You can have your time options in a drop-down and only make the ones that have not been selected selectable whilst disabling the others.. This does not need a plugin/component.

Comment: @FirstIndex No, i dont want that. I want them all visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker or http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ directly without vue.

Answer (score 0):

[ElementUI](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US), a Vue component library, has this [timepicker component](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/time-picker).

I think the `selectableRange` may allow you to exclude hours from your timepickers dinamically, by passing custom available ranges. How to implement this depends a lot on your own code, though.

Comment: It won't work for me. I need them all visible (without the possibility to hide them).